# VPS with multiple installations of WordPress. Memcache and APC or just one or the other?

Tags: php, wordpress, memcached

I have a VPS that I will be running multiple installations of WordPress on. I have been looking at some caching solutions but I am not sure exactly what would be best. Right now, I am more worried about page speed than handling traffic. Also, I am somewhat confused about the differences between memcache and memcached. Would one, an other, or both be good for WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is a good solution if you need to share the same cache across multiples server.

If you don't APC will be faster !